# Extending an abstract jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I created a jQuery plugin which queries the server via ajax and displays a popup.  I then wanted another one on a different page which returns some different data and displays it.  The way I implemented it, the plugin would send data indicating what page it was on to the server, the server would get the data and send back the type of data, and the client would display it as appropriate for the given type of data.

My approach obviously has a lot to be desired.  Instead, is it possible to make an abstract version of the plugin, and then extend it to for each particular application so it displays it correctly (i.e. get rid of the switch statement)?  Also, how can I get away from using an id on the popup (i.e. #screenshot) so each can be styled individually?  Thanks

```
ayb={};
$("a.screenshot").screenshotPreview();

function contact(data)
{
    return '<dl><dt>Name:</dt><dd>'+data.firstname+' '+data.lastname+'</dd>'
    +'<dt>Account:</dt><dd>'+data.account_name+'</dd>'
    +'<dt>Name:</dt><dd>'+data.firstname+' '+data.lastname+'</dd>'
    +((data.title)?'<dt>Title:</dt><dd>'+data.title+'</dd>':'')
    +'<dt>User Name:</dt><dd>'+data.username+'</dd>'
    +'<dt>Password:</dt><dd>'+data.password+'</dd>'
    +'<dt>Communication Method:</dt><dd>'+data.communication_method+'</dd>'
    +((data.email)?'<dt>Email:</dt><dd>'+data.email+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.account_phone)?'<dt>Account Phone:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.account_phone)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.phone)?'<dt>Direct Phone:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.phone)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.mobile_phone)?'<dt>Mobile Phone:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.mobile_phone)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.account_fax)?'<dt>Account Fax:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.account_fax)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.fax)?'<dt>Direct Fax:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.fax)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.address || data.location)?'<dt>Address:</dt><dd>'+data.address+((data.address && data.location)?'<br>':'')+data.location+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.email)?'<dt>Email:</dt><dd>'+data.email+'</dd>':'')
    +'</dl>';
}
function account(data)
{
    return '<dl><dt>Name:</dt><dd>'+data.name+'</dd>'
    +((data.phone)?'<dt>Account Phone:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.phone)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.fax)?'<dt>Account Fax:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.fax)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.address || data.location)?'<dt>Address:</dt><dd>'+data.address+((data.address && data.location)?'<br>':'')+data.location+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.vertical_markets)?'<dt>Primary Market:</dt><dd>'+data.vertical_markets+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.priority)?'<dt>Priority:</dt><dd>'+data.priority+'</dd>':'')
    +'</dl>';
}
function user(data)
{
    return '<dl><dt>Name:</dt><dd>'+data.firstname+' '+data.lastname+'</dd>'
    +'<dt>User Name:</dt><dd>'+data.username+'</dd>'
    +((data.phone)?'<dt>Direct Phone:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.phone)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.mobile_phone)?'<dt>Mobile Phone:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.mobile_phone)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.fax)?'<dt>Direct Fax:</dt><dd>'+display_phone(data.fax)+'</dd>':'')
    +((data.email)?'<dt>Email:</dt><dd>'+data.email+'</dd>':'')
    +'</dl>';
}
function getUrlVars(href)
{
    //Returns object based on variables in url.  Used to send data to GET
    var vars = {}, hash, hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}


(function( $ ){
    $.fn.screenshotPreview = function() {
        //Apply to links to get a preview of the link

        //Config - Set popup's distance from the cursor
        ayb.screenshot={};
        ayb.screenshot.xOffset = 20;
        ayb.screenshot.yOffset = 10;
        ayb.screenshot.showing=false;

        this.hover(function(e)
        {
            if(!ayb.screenshot.showing){
                ayb.screenshot.title = this.title;this.title = "";//Prevent title from being displayed,and save for later to put back    
                var url=getUrlVars(this.href);
                ayb.screenshot.timeoutID=window.setTimeout(function() {
                    ayb.screenshot.showing = true;
                    url.task="getPopup";   //specify task
                    ayb.screenshot.ajax=$.ajax({
                        url:    'index.php',
                        data: url,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            //Determine how to display returned data
                            switch (data.type)
                            {
                                case 'contact':var string=contact(data);break;
                                case 'account':var string=account(data);break;
                                case 'user':var string=user(data);break;
                                case 'project':var string=project(data);break;
                                default:var string='Error';
                            }
                            $("body").append('<div id="screenshot">'+((ayb.screenshot.title != '')?'<h3>'+ayb.screenshot.title+'</h3>':null)+string+"</div>");                                 
                            $("#screenshot")
                            .css("top",(e.pageY - ayb.screenshot.yOffset) + "px")
                            .css("left",(e.pageX + ayb.screenshot.xOffset) + "px")
                            .fadeIn("fast");                    
                        },
                    dataType: 'json'
                    });
                },250); //Wait 1/4 of a second before requesting data from server
            }
        },
        function()
        {
            //When not hover
            if (typeof ayb.screenshot.ajax == 'object') {ayb.screenshot.ajax.abort();}
            window.clearTimeout(ayb.screenshot.timeoutID);
            this.title = ayb.screenshot.title;    
            $("#screenshot").remove();
            ayb.screenshot.showing = false;
        });    
        this.mousemove(function(e)
        {
            $("#screenshot").css("top",(e.pageY - ayb.screenshot.yOffset) + "px").css("left",(e.pageX + ayb.screenshot.xOffset) + "px");
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: would help if you were more detailed about which parts you want abstracted, and how you want to use them. Can define all sorts of options for plugin either in a javascript options object, or by using `data-` attributes in markup. As for style, why can't you add different classes to main content of each type? Not clear what the style issue is...details would help

Comment: @charlietfl.  The part I want separate is primarily how I receive the data and then use the client to present it using something like `string=contact(data);`  Based on your comment, sounds like I could (and should!) define some sort of option which can even be a callback function which deals with displaying the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ideas that might help. First is using `data-` attributes in the markup:

```
<a href="#" class="screenshot" data-type="user">User Link</a>
```

Next is creating a more generic template method. The use type can be taken from the html `data-type` and by adding the class of same type ( or some other protocol related to type) you can have different css for different use cases

DEMO JS:

```
(function ($) {

    var shotTemplate = function (data, type) {
        this.shot = {
            start: '<div id="screenshot" class="' + type + '">',
            end: '</div>},'
        };
        this.user = function () { 
            /* not suggesting "data.type" protocol, was just simple for my demo*/
            return '<div class="user_class">' + data.user + '</div>';
        };
        this.contact = function () {
            return '<div class="contact_class">' + data.contact + '</div>';
        };
        this.account= function () {
            return '<div class="account_class">' + data.account + '</div>';
        };

        return this.shot.start + this[type]() + this.shot.end;

    };  



    $.fn.screenshotPreview = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $el = $(this);
            /* isolate screenshot to this instance*/
            var $screenshot;
            $el.hover(function () {
                $.post(url,data,function( response){
                        $screenshot = $(shotTemplate(response, $el.data('type')));
                        $('body').append($screenshot);
                });
            }, function () {
                $screenshot.remove();
            })

        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```css
#screenshot.user{background:navy;color:white}
#screenshot.contact{background:#444;color:white}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wceDc/

I kept demo simple to allow focusing on concepts and not clutter code with positioning

Comment: Thanks charlietfl!  Your implementation was a great job of taking my hackish start and making it elegant.  Another alternative which I will try is make the default just output the GET data, but have option for a call back.  I will post the results, but your solution was just what I was looking for.  Thanks again!

Comment: my ideas are only that..ideas... can use data from server to do a lot, can set up options within plugin to do things ...lots of ways to improve it

Comment: One more question.  Please explain your use of `this[type]()`.

Comment: might also look at using a templating plugin like `handlebars` to make the manual string coding easier also

Comment: `this[type]()` is object notation to call the proper function based on `type` passed to function from element. Would be same as writing `this.account()` as example, but allows calling method needed using a variable

Comment: Never used handlebars.  I do something similar with PHP, and will consider in the future.  Thanks